# How has Voyager not run out of shuttlecraft?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

I’ve been re-watching Star Trek: Voyager, lately. Over the first three seasons, Voyager loses multiple shuttlecraft. How many shuttlecraft does Voyager have?

Does the ship have some sort of large replication technology to instantly build new shuttlecraft as they are lost? A ship as small as an Intrepid class couldn’t have that many shuttlecraft in her shuttlebay(s).

Comment: I believe it is a narrative decision, most of the time Voyager does not run short of things unless a shortage is needed to drive the story. It always bugged me that Voyager still looked pristine at the end of the run. If you care about attrition watch Galactica, which more or less fell apart by the end.

Answer (score 5):

Voyager did not posses the [industrial replicators](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Industrial_replicator) necessary for the wholesale synthesis of new shuttlecraft. However we do know that the crew were capable of building new shuttlecraft, as evidenced by the creation of the [Delta Flyer](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Delta_Flyer) and [its creatively named successor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Delta_Flyer_II).

I don't know how many shuttlecraft Voyager started with, but presumably any that were destroyed could have been replaced in the same manner as the Delta Flyer, given that they were simpler and smaller.